# How can I set the Source property of the jQuery UI Autocomplete plug-in to the contents of a html table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

In a page, I have both a *textbox* (using the **jQuery UI Autocomplete** plug-in) and a *table* containing some data (let's say first name and last name).
What I want is to set the *source* property of the *plug in* to the contents of the *html table*, is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by building up an array of the content that you want to pull out of the table and setting the source of the `Autocomplete` plugin to the array. Here's a fiddle I just put together to demonstrate this as a proof-of-concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwnace/494qajef/

**EDIT:** If you post the markup for your HTML table, I can update the example to match your specific implementation.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted but I din't know how to build the array. Your answer is very helpful as it is, I can take it from here. Thanks again.